# Docker django mysql.sock in different location

Tags: mysql, django, docker, containers

I'm trying to containerize my django file, and I keep running into the issue:`(2006, ’Can\‘t connect to local MySQL server through socket \‘/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock\’ (2 “No such file or directory”)`

I found out later mysql.sock is in this location:`/tmp/mysql.sock` instead of `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, how do I change the location for docker to see `/tmp/mysql.sock`

Here is my docker-composr.yml:

```
    version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepassword

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I have followed the instructions on the mysql docker website to link mysql instance to a container

EDIT: I read another stack overflow similar to this, I changed my django code to `'HOST': '127.0.0.1'` in `DATABASES` now I get : `(2006, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'127.0.0.1\' (111 "Connection refused")')`

Answer (score 0):

Your host should be db.  When using docker-compose, you address different servers by their service name.

So, in settings.py, you should have:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'HOST': 'db',
         ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to your containerized MySQL server both inside and outside of the container, you'll first need to make sure the port is mapped on the host machine:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    ...
```

That will allow you to access MySQL using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` directly on your host machine.

If you want to be able to run Django in both the `web` container and also on the host, you'll need to override the `DATABASES` setting depending upon the scenario. The `web` container will need to use a `HOST` value of `db`, whereas your local machine will need a value of `localhost`.